# Surrogate Key Generation Across Multiple Tables Using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, timestamp

I want to get surrogate keys for my user table(s) in MySQL. I'm  sure concatinating an incrementing value + a timestamp would get me unique keys across multiple tables but how do I get the incremental value for the class's persistence table before I persist it to the database.

Answer (score 1):

let hibernate do it for you using one of their key generators.  If you *must* define your own key scheme, you will have to write your own generator.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with getting the current system time in millis then assigning this as the ID? I want something a bit more unique then an auto-incrementing field (which is what an @Generated tag is giving me at the moment with MySQL). I want keys that will be unique across several tables not just one

Comment: Yes, because, depending on the resolution of your database's CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, you could have two objects being inserted at the same exact moment in time. How can you get more unique than an auto-incrementing field, which is guaranteed to be unique already?

Comment: @user398371, I don't think its possible with mysql to do that.  Oracle supports it -- I think you define a sequence and then tell each table to use that sequence.